# call some query on page load [Codeigniter]

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

How to call a `query` on page load / page ready on codeigniter ? i'm not understand how to call query using ajax or javascript. for example : call an update query.
thanks

Comment: normally you can't. query is called in controller or model. use ajax to call a controller which defined to call a query

Comment: hmm how to call a controller in ajax ?

Comment: sorry i'm new in ajax programming

Comment: just fill the url section in ajax function with url to the controller, ex: url: 'http://localhost/yourapp/yourcontroller/yourfunction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well i dont know exactly what you want but i think this might help you .

copy this script in the view where you want to load query .

if you need more help then describe a little bit more about what you want

```
<script>


 $(document).ready(function(){
         $.ajax({
             method : 'get',
             url    : '<?php echo site_url("controller/method");?>'
             success: function(responce){
                         // you can alert this responce or print this in any html element
                         alert(responce);
                         //  $('p').html(responce);

                 }   
         })

   })
```